# How do you add equations in questions or answer?

Tags: support

What formating tips can be of help to write detailed equations? The editing help doesn't seem to be obvious. I couldn't find one. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Do you know latex? Basically, the equations are just latex math between `$–$` for inline math and `$$–$$` for display math. If you don't know, you probably might need to learn latex as it'll be too much to write in an answer. However, if you do know latex and have trouble formatting it, I can post a few examples in an answer. Let me know...

Answer (score 3):

See

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex

The inline editing unfortunately buries the help sidebar, but if you press shift+click on edit, you'll see a link on the sidebar to

http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/

Comment: Thanks. @Yoda's hint was enough though.